# Flipper 0.192.0 "No Application Selected" error for React Native iOS devices

Tags: ios, react-native, flipper

I'm attempting to use flipper after upgrading my react native project. For context my project has the following:

- React Native version: 0.71.4
- Flipper version 0.192.0
- Xcode 14.1

Android devices work as expected with Flipper, only iOS seems to not show up.

Steps I've taken so far have been mostly inspired by the [official docs](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/)

My Podfile contains the following:

```
 use_react_native!(
    ...
    :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug"], { 'Flipper' => '0.192.0' }),
    ...
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    react_native_post_install(
      installer
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

end
```

I've also updated my AppDelegate.m to include

```
#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>
```

When I run `pod install --repo-update` the pods install successfully, my app runs fine but it doesn't appear in Flipper, neither do most plugins. [image]

Any tips to get this working would be great - thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on my react-native Android app.

Already tried the manual and the automatic setup from the official doc, updating the desktop app and there are no warnings on flipper doctor.

None of the steps above helped me. :(